EMR step failing, with error 'User application exited with status 1'
I am running an EMR cluster and when I try to run it is failing at one step and there is no much information neither in the EMR logs nor in the yarn logs.
The only information I have is the following:
24/04/22 12:23:59 INFO Client: 
 client token: N/A
 diagnostics: User application exited with status 1
 ApplicationMaster host: ip-xxx-xx-34-xxx.ap-south-1.compute.internal
 ApplicationMaster RPC port: xx285
 queue: default
 start time: 1713788609373
 final status: FAILED
 tracking URL: http://ip-xxx-xxx-36-xxx.ap-south-

1.compute.internal:20888/proxy/application_17xxxx78656_0002/
     user: hadoop
24/04/22 12:23:59 ERROR Client: Application diagnostics message: User application exited with status 1
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Application application_1xxxxx878656_0002 finished with failed status
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.run(Client.scala:1321)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.YarnClusterApplication.start(Client.scala:1754)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:1075)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:194)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:217)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:91)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:1167)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:1176)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
24/04/22 12:23:59 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
24/04/22 12:23:59 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /mnt/tmp/spark-df5b4b24-b189-4046-ba16-09e1c9b26932
24/04/22 12:23:59 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /mnt/tmp/spark-995df76d-bf87-4fbc-ab51-81b8de8c998e
Command exiting with ret '1'

Any help is much appreciated.
Thank you all for your time.
